# Switching Cartesian and Polar Coordinates

Tags: geometry

[image: Valid XHTML]

I passed by this image long time ago, and I am now wondering if this can happen anytime.

Suppose we have the cycloid, given with equations $x=R(t-\sin{t}), y=R(1-\cos{t})$. On wikipedia, it says that

> A cycloid is the curve traced by a point on the rim of a circular wheel as the wheel rolls along a straight line without slippage.

Well, then suppose the equation of the cycloid could be manipulated to the form $y=f(x)$. (Although in Wikipedia, it says that a closed-form is not possible).

Suppose I changed $x$ to $\theta$ and $y$ to $r$, just as the image does, and get $r=f(\theta)$. If I added a constant, $R'$ so that the final equation became $r=f(\theta)+R'$.

Would this equation give us the curve traced by a point on the circle, rolling around another circle with radius $R'$? (Namely, [Epicycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid))

Comment: @Roby5: Normally, we would substitute $x=r\cos{\theta}, y=r\sin{\theta}$ to switch an Cartesian equation to Polar. In that case, when graphed, Cartesian equation and Polar equation both give the same graph. But my question is not about getting the 'same graph'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a closed form of the inverse doesn't exist we can still explore it via technology. Lets define $H(t)=t-\sin t$ and hence the function you are interested in is:

$$y=R\left(1-\cos \left(H^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{R}\right)\right)\right)$$

A rectangular graph of this looks like: ($R=1$ as $R$ really only changes scale).

[image]

Now if we change $x$ and $y$ to $\theta$ and $r$ as desired (and add in a radius) we are looking at the function:

$$r=R\left(1-\cos \left(H^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{R}\right)\right)\right)+R_0$$

This can be plotted (in blue) and compared to an epicycloid (in red).

In the following diagram $R=1$ and $R_0=1$.

[image]

So they are not the same curves.

Exploring different ratios of $R$ to $r$ in the epicycloid makes it appear that maybe the two curves approach each other asymptotically...

[image]

[larger version here of last image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKBJr.jpg)